# Adding virtual hosts for apache

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, virtualhost

I have IIS installed on my windows 7 which uses default port 80 and can be accessed at `http://localhost`. Now I have installed XAMPP as well and set the port 8081, so I can access it at `http://localhost:8081`.

Now, I want to add virtual host only for the xampp so that I can access it via **`http://test/`** instead of `http://localhost:8081`. I dont want to make any changes in IIS address and want to keep its address same. For that purpose, I have added virtual host in my xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-conf file ie.,

```
NameVirtualHost *:8081
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName test
    ServerAlias test
</VirtualHost>
```

I have restarted the apache but still can not access the address **`http://test`**. Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made XAMPP listen on Port 8081 rather thank 80 meaning that

```
http://test/
```

needs to be

```
http://test:8081/
```

Without a port number in a URL you are just referring to the default port (I.e. port 80 for http)

*Update:*
This is actually possible, however IIS and Apache (XAMPP) need to use different IP addresses and only bind to port 80 on there own IP address.
http://www.iislogs.com/steveschofield/iis7-post-44-iis7-and-apache-on-the-same-machine

If you can't touch IIS then the only alternative would be to use a proxy script to show a site on IIS which would proxy to 8081.

Comment: Is there any way to get it working without the port number in the url?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:
Go to: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
And add this to the bottom of the file:

=============

## 127.0.0.1     your.domain.com

Step 2:
Go to [your XAMPP directory]/apache/conf/httpd-xampp.conf

Step 3:
Go to the bottom of the file and copy & paste this code:

=============

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "[PATH TO YOUR CUSTOM FOLDER]"
   ServerName your.domain.com

   <Directory "[PATH TO YOUR CUSTOM FOLDER]">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

=============

- Replace [PATH TO YOUR CUSTOM FOLDER] to the folder where your files are located.
  Ex: C:/my/www/folder/
- your.domain.com must be the same on Step 1 & Step 3

Step 4:
Stop Apache on XAMPP, wait for 5 seconds, then click "Start" to start again your Apache.

If all things go well, you can go to your browser, type your.domain.com 
and it will now happily point to your custom local folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Top Best selected answer :**

Just You need to change only 3 files:

1. httpd.conf from conf
2. httpd-vhost from vhost file
3. host file from windows host file

Easy steps to do. You can do by yourself. Just follow the link below:

[**Make multiple virtual host on XAMPP**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=15&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7hsGEyMnLAhXnC5oKHaxdBKE4ChC3AggnMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DKDYrkJJff3I&usg=AFQjCNHDt0jbMix3FQeeqWG3OWBZaIi14Q&sig2=kJFZa2C1wCqReWGtSyjJGA&bvm=bv.117218890,d.bGs)